# Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009: Error executing code: Wrong argument types in variable assignment

Tags: customization, axapta, x++

I have added an object member to InventMovement class and have created one parameter method for the same but following line of code is popping up above error:

```
movement.parmProdJournalId(this.JournalId);

JournalId parmProdJournalId(JournalId _prodJournalId = prodJournalId)
{
    ;
    prodJournalId =  _prodJournalId;
    return prodJournalId;
}
```

After adding the object member and parameter method I have also compile forward InventMovement but no success. Will appreciate if anyone of you could help me in this regard

Rgds

PS: I am doing the same thing which is mentioned in this blog post: http://www.artofcreation.be/2009/04/04/wrong-argument-types-in-variable-assignment/

Comment: could you please provide some code, mainly for `parmProdJournalId`? And which object is `this`?

Comment: The first line i.e. movement.parmProdJournalId(this.JournalId); has been added to insert method of 'ProdJournalProd' table and rest of the code is added to InventMovement class. 'this' is referring to 'ProdJournalProd' table.

Comment: What type is prodJournalId? You haven't shown where it is declared.

Comment: @Jay, I have declared prodJournalId in classDeclaration of InventMovement and it's type is ProdJournalId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped the ***AOS***, renamed ***AXAPD.AOI*** file and restarted the ***AOS***. This resolved the problem. I got this solution from other forum where also I posted this question.

Comment: you should accept your answer since it helped you. Just click the checkbox to the left of the answer below the upvotes/downvotes count.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of strange, should work.
I could not reproduce your problem, but once had a similar problem. Solved it by re-compiling and synchronizing every involved class and table (more than once).
Also make sure nobody else is using any of these objects, maybe best is to restart the AOS.

EDIT (after comment on question):
Another possibility: it seams that you are also mixing `JournalId` and `ProdJournalId`.
I think the parameter and return value of `parmProdJournalId` should also be `ProdJournalId`.
Just try this one:

```
ProdJournalId parmProdJournalId(ProdJournalId _prodJournalId = prodJournalId)
{
    ;
    prodJournalId =  _prodJournalId;
    return prodJournalId;
}
```

could not try it myself since I could'nt reproduce the error

Comment: you mean restart the AOS or the machine?

Comment: the AOS... sometimes (compiled) code is cached in it (as I heard). Also editing/adding to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't restart the AOS, delete the local cache files of the client might work, i.e. *.auc from:
C:\Documents and Settings\Local Settings\Application Data